# How can I modify path of a user with no home folder?

Tags: rhel5, redhat, path

I have a user on my RHEL5 system whose home folder is /tmp. This user is for running some monitoring tasks, it doesn't represent a human being.

What are the options for modifying this user's PATH environment variable? I would like to add /usr/sbin to the user's PATH so that it has access to the `ethtool` command.

At the moment this user's path is `/usr/bin:/bin`.

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why do you want to change the path? you could simply start ethtool with it's full path

```
# /usr/sbin/ethtool
```

As far as I remember though ethtool doesn't do much for a normal user as it requires more privileges, but I might be wrong as it has been quite some time since I used it last.

Comment: Because I'm running a script which calls ethtool. I suppose I could modify the script because the other machine the script is running on will have ethtool in the same place, but that feels like the wrong solution.

Comment: But it's the solution I'll accept!

Answer (score 2):

you could change this in /etc/profile. There should be already a statement to set these paths for root.

Answer (score 2):

I would just give the user a home folder like any other user, and set the appropriate configurations there.   Having a user who's home folder is /tmp, which is also writeable by other users is iffy from a security point of view.

You didn't mention what shell the user was configured for - that's important as well.

Comment: The shell is /bin/sh. As for the user not having a normal home folder, that's just how I found it - I suppose I could speak with the UNIX guys here and see what they say, but the fact is the other machine's PATH is correctly set despite there being a non-standard home folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could also probably add a symlink to ethtool inside /usr/bin

i.e.

ln -s /usr/sbin/ethtool /usr/bin/ethtool

This would circumvent having to mess with the fake user's path.

Comment: This is bad security.

Answer (score 0):

First run: `#:id FAKE` and copy the uid.

Using that result, supplement for the word FAKE in the If statement below.

```
if [ `id -g` = FAKE]; then
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin/
fi
```

Add these lines to your /etc/profile.

Test it with: `$:sudo -u FAKE echo $PATH`

If that doesn't stick at first, you can force the export by using sudo. `$:sudo -u FAKE export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/ethtool` and then run the test again.

Comment: You can't put the name of the executable in the `PATH` - only the directory.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that it was a guess on my part.